# Need Password and username validation for login page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a login page where the i have entered script to check the empty username and password,  now want to change the class of password input to "has- error" and also do the same for username if the data entered by he user is wrong, ie if the username entered by the user does not exist in my database then the username field must show error and if the password is wrong the password field must show error. I am new to php and bootstrap which i have used for my page
javascript code is

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/formValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateText(id)
{
    if($("#"+id).val()==null || $("#"+id).val()=="")
    {
        var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
        div.addClass("has-error");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var div = $("#"+id).closest("div");
        div.removeClass("has-error");
        return true;
        }
}

$(document).ready(function()
 {
    $("#custbtn").click(function()
    {
        if(!validateText("cusername"))
        {       
            return false;               
            }
        if(!validateText("cpassword"))
        {
            return false;               
            }
        $("form#loginfom").submit();
        });
});
</script>
```

the page code is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class=" login-panel panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Customer Login</h3>
      </div>
      <div class=" panel-body">
        <form role="form" id="loginfom" action="../Connections/Logincust.php" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="cusername" name="cusername" type="username" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" type="password" value="" autofocus>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->

            <button type="button" id="custbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> Login </button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the code for logincust.php

Comment: What error are you getting.

Comment: You can very simply do `$('#cpassword').addClass("has-error")` (I assume the space in "has- error" is a typo)

Comment: Sorry, not exactly an answer to your question but there is something really important about your project imho, you said :  
_and also do the same for username if the data entered by he user is wrong, ie if the username entered by the user does not exist in my database_  
I think you couldn't do that. This will give to the users the possibility to "try" some usernames to see if it exists.  
Prefer a "generic" error like "Password OR username is not valid" where the users don't really knows what the database table contains.
More details on [Security SO](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Tibrogargan where should i add this script as i am having the action for the form and all the values are posted to the php script in that form

Comment: You're asking for someone to tell you how to modify code you have not posted

Comment: @Tibrogargan  sorry i didnt read your post correctly

Comment: @Tibrogargan i will post the code

Comment: @SyedFarazAli it will be good if you can use third-party plugin.custom code will give you lot of pain so please go with http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/